# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin cross-domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, cross-domain

Im using chrome to try and access my local server.
Also using jquery-2.0.3 and jquery-mobile-1.4.0-rc.
My page url is:
file:///C:/Users/....../index.html

My code looks like this:

```
var login = {
    in: function(){

        var ajaxUrl = "http:// localhost/Account/Login/";
        var loginModel = {
            UserName: $("#userMame").val(),
            Password: $("#password").val(),
            RememberMe: true
        };
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(loginModel),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=windows-1255",
            scriptCharset: "windows-1255",
            headers : {Accept : "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST,GET",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Authorization,X-Requested-With"},
            crossDomain : true,
            success: login.inSuccess,
            error: login.inFailure
        });
    },
    inSuccess: function(obj) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    inFailure: function(obj, b, c) {
        alert("Failure");
    }
}

$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {

    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

I keep on getting the same error when invoking login.in():

OPTIONS http:// localhost/Account/Login/ Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

As you can see I have tried everything already . . .

Comment: Are you accessing your page through a server (i.e. `http://localhost`) or open it locally (i.e. `file://...`)?  For AJAX calls to work, you need to use the first approach.

Comment: If You test your code no firefox, this problem won't occur.

Answer (score 1):

> For security reasons JavaScript's access to the file system on the
>   client is restricted - consider whether you would want (somebody
>   else's) JavaScript to read your sensitive documents.
>
> Even when experimenting it's best to work with a realistic topology,
>   serve things from the server that would be served from there in the
>   real system.
>
> It's really easy to set up a web server such as Apache to point to
>   your development directory, so the "server" is just your desktop in
>   disguise. Hence the edit/test cycle is really quick.

[Using AJAX to read local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files#answer-6923816)