# Changing Data for HighMaps JQuery to a local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, highmaps

I am using this [code - Jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/color-axis/) to create a datamap of the United States. I would like to modify the data set in the example by using a file stored locally.

The data appears to be stored in a file located at: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/us-population-density.json.

I changed the filename in to be a local drive, but the chart won't load. What changes do I need to make?

Reference to my local drive:

`$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=C:/us-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {`

Comment: You can't load files from drive using AJAX (at least not in Chrome). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file) and many others..

Comment: Not true. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json

Comment: You need to have any webserver to load data, because browsers block loading files from filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $.getJSON('us-population-density.json', function(data) {
```

According to to [highcharts reference](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json)