# Setting variable equal to local JSON file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set a variable in JavaScript to a local JSON file stored on computer?

```
var data = c/path/path/data.json
```

Comment: Will end user have this file in his machine ?

Comment: You can set a variable to hold a string which contains any path at all, yes. Doesn't mean you'll be able to **read the contents of this file** though.

Comment: XY Problem? - What are you trying to achieve? Perisistent storage? Or just some sort of storage in your program?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can access the file system with JavaScript the answer is *yes and no*. **If you are using a tool like node.js then yes** you can access the file system using JavaScript. **If you are trying to access the file system from the browser then no** JavaScript does not natively have that capability.

It really does not matter what you are trying to access on the file system. It could be JSON, jpg, or gif... If you are using a browser it is not possible..

However you can make **[ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)** call to a server and get files that way. i.e. JSON files... You can also store information using JavaScript using the '**[localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**' method built into JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Ajax request to get the external json.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "c/path/path/data.json",
}).done(function(JsonToGet) {
  var data = JsonToGet;
  //Management of the JSON with 'data' variable. 
});
```

Comment: This will not work on any main stream browsers. Some browsers let you disable security and allow it but in most circumstances it will not work.

Comment: [Try to follow this link! It may explain better... **using-ajax-to-read-local-files**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files)

Comment: You're right. The way I write is valid for a Rest web service, for example. Not recommended for local files.