# How to reload content according exac time without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm preparing simple digital signage script which require time scheduling.
I was able to do it with javascript with refreshing every 15 minutes.
But my question is, how can I measure the time and change the content on exact hour without refreshing the page?

My page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900" >
<title>Signage</title>
<style>
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
</style>
<script>
function src() { 
    var Day = "day.html";
    var Lunch = "lunch.html";
    var Evening = "evening.html";
    var Src;

    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var day = new Date().getDay();

    if (hour >= 10 && hour <= 13 && day >= 1 && day <=5) {
        Src = Lunch;    
    }       

    else if (hour >= 7 && hour <= 19)   {
        Src = Day;
            }

    else  {
        Src = Evening;
            }

document.getElementById('signage').src = Src; 

}

</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="src();">
<iframe scrolling="no" id="signage" src="about:blank" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want your page to refresh every X minutes ? And depending on the time, it will load day/lunch/evening ?

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page at all... I just want to change the content on exact time.

Comment: But what is "exact time" ? Every second ? So that when it's 6h59 it's evening and then 7h it changed to day ?

Comment: For example: Lunch time is between 11am to 2pm. So at exact 11am the content will change to lunch and after exact at 2pm change it back to day offer. The same with evening.

Comment: A question, for the lunch you use `day >= 1 && day <=5`, why ? Does it means that whenever it's the weekend, the script will only be Day/Evening ?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time][1]

Comment: Yes... Over weekend is no lunch offer active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your page to refresh automatically after a certain time period, you can use javascript's `setInterval()` function.

```
setInterval(function() { window.location.reload(); } , timePeriod );
```

Comment: I don't need this.... it's refreshing it self every 15 minutes. You can see it in meta tag.

Comment: What you are looking for is AJAX. But i am guessing you have not hosted this website anywhere.If you run this on a local server you will be able to achieve this very easily with jqeury. 
Due to security reasons you cannot use AJAX to fetch files from file system directly.

Comment: Exactly... I just need to change the content. The thing is... if the content is some video... it can't be refreshed every x minutes. So I was hoping for something to check the time in background and when it comes to the change hour, it will do the content change.

Comment: I am running it on local pc. No problem with security.

Comment: No the problem is not that you can, problem is you cannot. It is not allowed for the javascript to access the file system.

Comment: You may use apache server to host your files locally using php. It is very easy to setup. You can look up the web and get it done in no time.

Comment: I know, I could do it in php with localhost... but the idea was make it simple as possible.

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files

Comment: SetInterval is deprecated because of its behaviour, you'd better use setTimeout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in head

```
<script> document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setTimeout(function() {src();}, 5000 /*5 sec*/)); </script>
```

Comment: Tried... didn't help.