# Reading Local File with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried reading a local text file with Javascript(JQuery). With the following code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'file:///C:/Users/kola/Desktop/b/data_file_text',
    error: function(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    },
    success: function(e)
    {
        console.log(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

At the end of the execution, Error Method was triggered. Accessing the argument(e) returned. I Got the following Jquery Object.

```
readyState: 4
responseText: "My Expected Data"
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
....
```

Why will it triggered error and everything seems OK. Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AJAX to read local files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files)

Comment: I understand that. Try running the code, if I got error because of Security Concern, how came I can still access the file's data from error method?